# Map on filter giving compilation issue

Tags: java, java-stream

What could be the issue here ?
I get the following error on compilation:

```
error: cannot find symbol
                                .collect(toList())
                                         ^
  symbol:   method toList()
  location: class stocks
 error: invalid method reference
                                .map(Stock::getSymbol)
                                     ^
  cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method getSymbol()
    location: class Stock
```

Class Stock does have a public method getSymbol

```
   static class StockUtil{

            public static Predicate<Stock> isLessThanLimit(Double limit){
                return s -> s.tick < limit;
            }

            public static String toUpperCase(String stock){
                return stock.toUpperCase();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Stock("AMZ",312.0),
                new Stock("Yahoo",212.0),
                new Stock("ORCL",512.0),
                new Stock("SAP",112.0),
                new Stock("Google",412.0),
                new Stock("FB",12.0),
                new Stock("TWT",315.0)));


            //print list of stock names below 400 in uppercase
            System.out.println(stocks.stream().filter(StockUtil.isLessThanLimit(400.0))
                    .map(Stock::getSymbol)
                    .map(StockUtil::toUpperCase)
                    .collect(toList())
                    );
```

Comment: *any* IDE will show you that it can't resolve `toList` here...

Comment: The answers below show how to solve the issue with `toList()` already. About `getSymbol()`: `Stock` does have a method `getSymbol()` with **no** parameters, and which is **not** static, correct? Are you sure it has been properly compiled? Third, as a small hint: your `toUpperCase()` method is not necessary, just use `String.toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make sure you use the complete reference to the method as

```
Collectors.toList()
```

or import statically

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

along with a `Stock` class somewhat as :

```
class Stock {
    String symbol;
    ...
    public String getSymbol() {...} //getter for symbol
    ...
}
```

[Ideone it!](https://ideone.com/1a5pkL)

Comment: Never knew what the issue is  - but accepting the answer for the first part.Would have resolved it with an appropriate IDE probably

Comment: @IUnknown `toList` is a static method exposed by `Collectors` api. Hence the issue is that you need to make sure it is imported properly.

Comment: @IUnknown Please refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-import-java/

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the method `toList()` or you forgot to do static import, try:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

no other changes expected in your code.

If you do not want to do static import:

```
System.out.println(stocks.stream().filter(StockUtil.isLessThanLimit(400.0))
                    .map(Stock::getSymbol)
                    .map(StockUtil::toUpperCase)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    );
```

Refer to java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) of Collectors for details.